# Как измерять "ШАГИ" в js?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, циклы

Я сейчас прохожу курс (не на youtube) и я остановился на циклах, и есть вопрос:
что означают **плюсы, минусы, знаки равно** тут:
[image: code]

если кто не понял, то я про `cout++`, эти плюски минусики и равно называют "ШАГИ" и вопрос в том как мне измерять или хотя бы понять что означают эти шаги, насколько они отнимают от числа или на сколько прибавляют, есть еще такой пример: `count++=2` может есть статья на эту тему, я искал и не чего не нашел(

Comment: Прочитайте https://learn.javascript.ru/operators , лучше целиком, но в частности вам нужны «Сокращённая арифметика с присваиванием»  и «Инкремент/декремент». По поводу использования в циклах см. https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for

Comment: Да и вообще обратите внимание на этот учебник — видимо, ваш курс не совсем полный или последовательный, если у вас возникают такие вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно прочитаю